# Use Keys in Key Locker

Tags: ingress

Straightforward question, can Keys be used while inside a Key Locker, such as remote charging or being consumed to link portals? Or do I have to take them out in order to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key Lockers are glorified capsules that only hold keys and don't take up inventory space.

If you want to use a key from a locker, you will have to take it out first.

Comment: They have one benefit over regular capsules. Keys in the locker do not consume inventory space.